# How to upload images by Javascript to a Node Server with multer.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, multer

I'm using the multer module on my Node Server.

**This is the Node js code:**

```
app.post('/image/', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
var response = [];
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
var file = 'temp_images' + '/' + req.file.filename;
fs.rename(req.file.path, file, function(err) {
if (err) {
        response.push({'result' : 'false'});
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
} else {
            CallOtherFunction(req.file.filename)
            response.push({'result' : 'true'});
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
});
```

Uploading images by using a html form, that looks like this works fine:

```
<form action="http://servertoupload/image/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input id='submit' type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

*** But how to achieve this by pure javascript, with no form elements?**



*** OR: How to disable page reload / loading of the 'response.push' Site for the client?**

Help very much appreciated, this is driving me crazy.

Comment: You can do it by making an `ajax` request for prevent the page to load and for file input, you can send it to the server by using javascript `formData()` class

Answer (score 0):

Using `fetch` and `FormData` you can accomplish this.

Change the HTML a little bit:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
<button type="button">Upload</button>
```

And then use JavaScript to respond to a button click:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if(document.querySelector('input').files.length === 0) return
  var file = document.querySelector('input').files[0]

  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('file', file)

  fetch('http://servertoupload/image/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  }).then(r => r.text()).then(console.log)
```

})

The response will be logged in the console.